# Customizing the UIImagePickerController for iPad

Tags: iphone, sdk

I was implementing an iPad application. For this I need to customize the UIImagePickerController, I mean to say that I need to implement it with out using UIPopOverViewController that is my requirement. I tried in many ways to support my requirement but I didn't su Is it possible to implement?. Can you guys please help on this.

Thanks in Advance,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the properties of the UIPopOverViewController proerties you can Customize the frame.